# Clone in simple_html_dom library

Tags: php, clone, simple-html-dom

I'm using `simple_dom_html` library. I have problem with node cloning.
I need to clone `tr` for some table, but `clone` just copy its. I'v tried to override `clone` method in `simple_html_dom_node` - not working.
This is fragment of my code:

```
$trNode = $this->_getClosestTrNode($node->parent()); //get closest table tr node
$tableBodyNode = $trNode->parent();
//clone tr nodes
for($j = 0; $j < $cloneCount; $j ++){
    $tr = clone $trNode;
    $tableBodyNode->appendChild($tr);
}
```

UPD:

```
$tr = unserialize(serialize($trNode));
```

Not good solution, because require a lot of memory.

Comment: What do do you mean by "does not work"? And what do you want to accomplish? I've tested it and it works as expected. The object is cloned

Comment: ``clone`` just copied tr's, but does not cloned. I need to clone them, because, in last part of code, I modify this table and when i change first row, changes also applying for all rows. http://gyazo.com/1f2d0367535a76f958644a58074164ca

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Ah, you're using **simple_html_dom**. I browsed the source code and the problem is with node (object) relationship (and all the circular parent-child references)

When you clone an object in PHP, the cloning process is superficial. That means only the outmost object is copied. This is because, in PHP by default, objects are passed as Reference and not by value.

Example code:

```
class A {}
class B {
    public $a;
    public function __construct(A $a) { $this->a = $a; }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B($a);
$c = clone $b;

print spl_object_hash($a) .'<br>';
print spl_object_hash($c->a).'<br>';
```

Output:

```
00000000449326660000000062d82106
00000000449326660000000062d82106
```

As you see the hash is the same.

The only way to change this behaviour is by overriding the [**`__clone()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php#object.clone) method, wish means changing the source code of **simple_html_dom** or extending each object defined by the library.

Serializing and unserializing works because PHP creates a string representation of the object and its properties (which include child objects). It takes so long because of all the circular references.

I suggest changing to another library, one that uses libxml as backend.

Comment: Sorry, but you use ``DOMDocument``, i use ``simple_dom_html`` library

Comment: Ah, you're right, I've missread simple_html_dom with simple_xml.

Comment: I also has different hash for objects, but values in table rows after updating are match.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i tried to change ``__clone()`` method in simple_html_dom_node class - not working, maybe I did something wrong. Only working solution it is use ``$tr = unserialize(serialize($trNode))`` but it required a lot of memory and my local server is crashing